# assignment of read-only variable

Tags: c++

```
class mainClass {
public:
    static const bool testB;

    void testFunction()
    {
         std::cout<<"We're here!";
         testB = true;
    }
};
```

When I run this I get the error which is in the subject. I've done a little research but could not get to the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: The problem is the `const` keyword. `const` stands for "constant". You're attempting to change the value of a constant, or read-only, variable.

Comment: `testB` is `const`, it can be initialized but not assigned.

Comment: And that's all it was. I feel like an idiot now. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a constant (read only variable) `testB`, and trying to change the value of it inside the method `testFunction` - this isn't allowed.   Imagine you had several other methods that tried to assign this value to different things (true/false) - it's not really a readonly constant, is it?

Try changing your code to do this instead:

```
static const bool testB = true;
```

If you really want to change the value of it, you need to change how it is declared - perhaps something like this:

```
static bool testB; // now you can change the value in whatever function you want
```